# Receive power for Bluetooth Audio

Tags: bluetooth

Does anyone know the typical receive power for a Bluetooth radio when receiving audio either A2DP or ATX?  I want to do some system power analysis to examine the radio power as part of the overall system for a TWS application.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean "Receiver Sensitivity"? If so, we'd need to know the PHY involved, I think. (I'm not familiar with TWS.)

Comment: I'm asking for the power (current consumption and voltage) for the radio receiver when streaming bluetooth audio.  TWS = true wireless stereo.  My interest is in the receiver so I'm not so concerned with the transmit power - that is on the other side of the link.  And I should perhaps also say that this is for EDR (extended data rate) Bluetooth, not BLE.  A dual-mode radio is fine as long as it is operating in EDR mode.

Comment: What Bluetooth chipset? Can you share all the details regarding your Bluetooth radio? If you have a datasheet to share that would be even better.
You can also empirically measure the input power if you are able to add an inline sense resistor or multimeter with the Bluetooth circuit VDD.

Comment: I am asking the question generally, so any chipset would work.  The one I'm thinking of is the CSR8645 but I'm only finding a data brief, not a data sheet.  Armed with the data sheet, I wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: And to explain why I'm OK with the answer for any chipset, I'm not expecting the receive power to vary by more than a factor of two from one chipset to another.  Yes, that is large but for the purpose of my analysis, it is fine - I'm just looking for the ballpark number.